# How do i get the values of multiple selection from a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

Can someone please provide a sample code or at least a method that I can use to get the string values of multiple selections in a JTable? I searched the web, but I found only examples of how to get values from a single selection. Based on that I tried to implement the code myself using loops, but it blew up on my face. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

JTable has a method for that :

```
    int[] selection = table.getSelectedRows();
```

Of course, this method returns the indices of the selected rows. You can use these indices to get the values you want from the the table model.

Comment: Keep in mind that those indices are in 'table-view coordinates' and not in model coordinates. So you need to transform them before going to the model

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
                System.out.println(selectedRows);
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = selectedRows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        System.out.println(model.getValueAt(selectedRows[i], 1));
                        model.removeRow(selectedRows[i]);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).